# Set up SenderID's record in DNS Host zone

Tags: dns

In order to avoid the Received-SPF: softfail error, i am setting the TXT records

```
v=spf1 a mx ip4:201.98.45.67 ip4:201.98.45.67 ~all
v=spf1 a mx ip4:212.38.97.34 ip4:212.38.97.34 ~all
```

in My DNS Hosed Zone.

The `201.98.45.67`, `212.38.97.34` are public IP addresses pointed to sites `gs.com` and `beta.gs.com`. From these sites I send emails.

But the public IP addresses are not fixed, they may change after every new build.

Is there a possible way to replace the ip4 with the domains `gs.com` and `beta.gs.com` in the DNS records.

I tried with

```
v=spf1 a mx mx:beta.gs.com ~all
v=spf1 a mx mx:gs.com ~all
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Are these on 2 separate domains, or 2 TXT records on 1 domain?

Comment: `in My DNS Hosed Zone.`  +1 for properly understanding your problem.

Comment: Have you completely read and understood [the syntax of SPF records](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax)? There are many ways to add hosts to SPF records, not all of them require the use of IP addresses... (hint, `a:`)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
"v=spf1 a mx include:beta.gs.com ~all" "v=spf1 a mx include:gs.com ~all"
```

Comment: The include assumes that `gs.com` has an SPF record.